# Can not access protected property PHP object

Tags: php

When i am trying to access object elements i get the following error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property
>   PHRETS\Models\Search\Record::$fields in
>   /var/www/html/PHRETS/retsphp.php:49

here is the object which is returned

```
object(PHRETS\Models\Search\Record)#36 (5) {
  ["resource":protected]=>
  string(8) "Property"
  ["class":protected]=>
  string(11) "Residential"
  ["fields":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "ListAgentMlsId"
    [1]=>
    string(21) "ListAgentStateLicense"
    [2]=>
    string(18) "ListAgentFirstName"
    [3]=>
    string(19) "ListAgentKeyNumeric"
    [4]=>
    string(17) "ListAgentLastName"
    [5]=>
    string(19) "ListingContractDate"
  }
  ["restricted_value":protected]=>
  string(4) "****"
  ["values":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    ["ListAgentMlsId"]=>
    string(6) "pi5683"
    ["ListAgentStateLicense"]=>
    string(8) "01968042"
    ["ListAgentFirstName"]=>
    string(5) "Noemi"
    ["ListAgentKeyNumeric"]=>
    string(9) "118522750"
    ["ListAgentLastName"]=>
    string(6) "Castro"
    ["ListingContractDate"]=>
    string(10) "2019-06-03"
  }
}
```

Tried to access like

```
$record->fields[0].ListAgentMlsId
or 
$record->resource
```

All create the same error Cannot access protected property

How can i access the values of this object ?

Comment: Can you access any other property in that **.php** page, or is the problem exclusive to that property alone?

Comment: The problem is with accessing any value in that object

Comment: Do you have your PHP Permissions set correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [definition](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/blob/8eb9c43dfea54760383e0fcba4f55468568f9fc2/src/Models/Search/Record.php#L79-L82) of class `PHRETS\Models\Search\Record`, You should use method `getFields()` to access protected property `$fields`, If you want to access value for specific field, Just use it likes array, e.g. `$record['ListAgentMlsId']`. Because Record class has implemented `ArrayAccess`.